# Static variable from parsed CSV?

Tags: php, static-variables, fgetcsv

Global variables are frowned upon, and often using a static variable is recommended in it's place.

I need to be able to have the variables I get from the CSV file, accessible to any function within the php file.

Is this possible to do if I'm parsing a CSV file for the variables?

For example, how can I make `$name` and `$table` available to any function in the file?:

```
<?php
$f_pointer=fopen("student.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(! feof($f_pointer)){
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
$name = $data[0];
$table = $data[3];
echo print_r($ar); // print the array
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class from this function and return the results from this as a member function. We can use a multidimensional array as our return.

```
class My_Class{

    public $array;

    public function get()
    {
        $this->array = array();

        while(! feof($f_pointer)){
            $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
            $name = $data[0];
            $table = $data[3];
            $this->array[] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'table' => $table,
                'ar' => $ar
            );
        }

        return $this->array();
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize it in this way:

```
$My_Class = new My_Class;
echo '<pre>', print_r($My_Class->get(), true),'</pre>';
```

Which will produce a multidimensional array with the data that we iterated through in our while case.